# How to save (trace) the execution route/sequences in debugger and Replay?

Tags: debugging, x64dbg

is it possible to save the step-by-step execution route of the program?

i.e. lets say in x64dbg the program executes one handle after another 
[image]

and so on, probably hundreds of calls...
But according to the specific function, it might show "YES" and "NO".

So, I want to save/remember the steps from the beginning to the "YES" window, and then compare it to the execution/steps, when it shows "NO".

So, I could see on **which handle** (specific logic in function) the difference happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use "Trace record" and "Run trace".

Using Trace record, the debugger records and highlights every instructions as you step through the code. You will easily know when the same instruction is executed twice by virtue of the highlighting.

[image]

When "Run trace" is enabled with "Trace record", the debugger additionally saves the code execution path along with the state of the registers and associated memory at each step.

[image]

Further read: https://x64dbg.com/blog/2016/07/09/introducing-contemporary-reverse-engineering-technique-to-real-world-use.html

Comment: so, later i can compare/replay that, right? thanks, i am newbie..

Comment: @T.Todua You can save the traces to a file which you can compare later. AFAIK `rr` and `qira` on linux support replaying traces but not x64dbg.